# loading lots of images to numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

I want to load blurred and unblurred images as my x and x hat respectively. I need to load a lot of images into NumPy arrays but that takes a lot of memory and time. The images are on my harddisk, organized into train dev and test folder, each holding 2 additional folders: one for the blurred images and one for the unblurred images, while both the blurred and unblurred versions share a name. I use the following code:

```
def get_list_img(data_dir,chunk_size):#, return_dict,procname):
    img_locations = natsorted([file.path for file in os.scandir(data_dir)])[0:chunk_size]
    return np.asarray([imread(file) for file in img_locations])


def get_data_from_folder(data_dir,chunk_size):
    x_dir = data_dir + 'input\\'
    y_dir = data_dir + 'regular\\'

    pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
    tx = pool.apply_async(get_list_img, (x_dir,chunk_size))
    ty = pool.apply_async(get_list_img, (y_dir,chunk_size))
    return tx.get(),ty.get()
```

is there a faster and memory-efficient way to do this?